# scalling problem in shapes and controllers of svg

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scale in component and shape javascript but it's not working with following svg .. can you guide me how to solve this issue???

```
<g text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" stroke="#000000" fill="#FFFFFF" type="svg-ext-proceng-pumpjet" id="SHE_6769b48c-0bde4e24">
<path d="M342,232A20,20 0 0 1 322,252A20,20 0 0 1 302,232A20,20 0 0 1 322,212A20,20 0 0 1 342,232" id="SHE_80a3b7ab-a1794e09"></path>
<path d="M302,232L322,212L342,232M310.8,223.2C316.87,230.58 316.87,241.22 310.8,248.6M333.2,223.2C327.13,230.58 327.13,241.22 333.2,248.6" id="SHE_41f771e5-37da4534"></path>
</g>
```